# RuntimeError:This command is using a remote connection in offline mode.[CondaError]

Tags: python-2.7, anaconda, conda

when I've created environment into conda, I got this error just after `Proceed` response:

```
[root@MyServer]#conda create -n py26 python=2.6 anaconda --offline

Fetching package metadata .........
Solving package specifications: ..............
......................
....
...
Proceed ([y]/n)? y


CondaError: RuntimeError(u'EnforceUnusedAdapter called with url https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64/jpeg-8d-0.tar.bz2\nThis command is using a remote connection in offline mode.\n',)
CondaError: RuntimeError(u'EnforceUnusedAdapter called with url https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64/jpeg-8d-0.tar.bz2\nThis command is using a remote connection in offline mode.\n',)
CondaError: RuntimeError(u'EnforceUnusedAdapter called with url https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64/jpeg-8d-0.tar.bz2\nThis command is using a remote connection in offline mode.\n',)
```

even that I can see that my env has created successfuly:

```
[root@MyServer]# conda env list
# conda environments:
#
py26                     /opt/Anaconda/Anaconda2-4.4.0/envs/py26
py27                     /opt/Anaconda/Anaconda2-4.4.0/envs/py27
root                  *  /opt/Anaconda/Anaconda2-4.4.0
```

is that Error influence environement I have created?

Answer (score 2):

After few hours of search I found out that this issue cames from a bug on the Conda version `4.3.x`: [Github](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/5443)

to fix this issue, you will have to install the Conda `4.4.x`

also, you have to check out the [UPDATE](https://conda.io/docs/release-notes.html#id24) on this version to enable conda in your shel:

Comment: Update link is broken.  :-(